# How to server side push data to client using jquery or javascript?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, tomcat

I want to push the data from server to web client. Now i have used the j2ee technology, i am using javascript and give a ajax call to server some intervel times then the data is showed to webclient. This process works fine. But i feel its overhead to server.I want to get the data from server when the new data comes to database then push the data to web client .Is any other any technologies or tomcat plugin available?

Comment: There is no way to do it. HTTP functions as a request-response protocol server can send response only if there was a request. which is usually accomplished using ajax calls

Comment: Long poll and Comet are two technologies you should have a look at.

Comment: web sockets seems more appropriate in your case even if it consumes a lot of server-side resource especially if you are using PHP. But with nodeJs it's better. There are other push tecnologies you could looking for. But simple way should be just for each ajax request you do, check a kind of hash on database which changed on each modification server side. If hash is different, send data to client using the callback of ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the "long polling" strategy.

It is a working solution. Though this is an ajax call it still reduces the server load. Websockets are another option, but this does not always work reliable, so you'd need a fallback anyway.

Comment: shall i use rabbitMq technology here?

Comment: No idea about that, "long polling" is a pretty simple strategy, no magic here. You just make a "normal" ajax request with one difference: the server side does _not_ return immediately, instead it simply sleeps/waits if nothing has to be reported. It only returns some json information snippet if an event occurred (or upon some timeout). Only then the client reacts and/or reestablishes the connection. That's all. http://blog.perplexedlabs.com/2009/05/04/php-jquery-ajax-javascript-long-polling/

Comment: k i will try and come back

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at APE push server: http://ape-project.org